# Guid is not foreign key after database is scaffolded. ASP.NET Core Identity 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET identity here but I am having a few issues I want to extend it with a few properties. I have added the class application user and it inherits from identity users.

```
public class UserInfo : IdentityUser 
{
    public virtual UserProfileInfo ProfileInformation { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfileInfo 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```
public class MISDBContext : IdentityDbContext<UserInfo> 
{
    public MISDBContext(DbContextOptions<MISDBContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<MISObject> MISobject { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> AppUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

As you can see it has created the link ok. But it created it with an Int instead of a guid. Also I don't see the `AccountController` code anywhere so that I can add my extra fields into the register event how Do i fix the id relationship to be sure it works correct.

Should I be using my `ApplicationUser` here on this line of my startup? Or should it be left as IdentityUser

```
  services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicaitonUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
```

My Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
     services.AddDbContext<MISDBContext>
      (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
             
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

[image]